# Strip HTML tagName with Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I am trying to separate HTML-tagName from HTML-Code. My HTML-Code is as follows:

```
<div id="MyDiv" style="left:100px; top:10px;" > some text in div
<strong>
<em> Some text for em
<p><b>b,  <span id="MySpan">span1,
```

After calling of REg-Ex I expect all valid HTML-Tagname from string. 
E.g. from above HTML-Code it should result something as follows: div, strong, em, p, b, span.
Here is my approach:

```
sTagName = sTagName.replace(/< *(.*) *>/, '$1');
alert(sTagName);
```

The above RegEx-Statement delivers for `< div >` results: `div` This is ok.
But it delivers for `< div stlye="..." >` results: `div stlye="..."` This is wrong.
I expect for it only a `div`.
In other words after space in HTML-Tagname the string should be deleted, so that I get div-Tagname.
For performance reasons I won't call the RegEx-Statement twice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Can't figure out what you're trying to do. Are you trying to match tags without attr/val's or strip attr/vals ?

Answer (score 1):

Via the dom;

```
var el = $("<div/>").append(html_string).find("*").each(function() {
    alert($(this).prop("tagName"));
});
```

Comment: Yes, perfectly! Do you know, whether it is faster (performance) than using of RegExp e.g. something as follows: `sTagName = sTagName.replace(/<\s*(\w+)[^/>]*>/, '$1');`

Comment: I was hasty. The DOM delivers some tagName twice and disordered. I can't use it. I'll try better with RegEx. Here are my approaches:`sTagName = sTagName.replace(/(<.*?>)(.*?)</mg, '$1' );` or here: `sTagName = sTagName.replace(/<\s*(\w+)[^/>]*>.*?</g, '$1' );` I couldn't find from very above link a solution for me :(